# Echo element if posts table is empy cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Basically I am trying to echo an element with some basic html saying "There are currently no posts" if the posts table is empty.

DB structure is ID, USER_ID, TITLE, BODY, CREATED, MODIFIED.

In the posts index the code is as follows:

```
   if(!empty($posts['Post']['title'])) {
                    echo $this->element('postslist');
            } else {
                    echo $this->element('noposts');
            }
```

The issue I am having is that the "noposts" element is being echoed regardless if there is data in there table or not..  Clearly I am doing something wrong.

Any and all help is appreciated!

edit:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 0
                    [title] => debugging away
                    [body] => 
Laaaadeee daaaaa


                    [created] => 2012-03-27 17:05:36
                    [modified] => 2012-03-27 17:05:36
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: can you try direct with the $_POST['title'], is it working ???

Comment: Can you post the contents of the $post array? echo pr($posts)

Comment: You do not use use $_POST directly because of possible security issues. In fact the title should be escaped by wrapping it with the CakePHP shortcut h().

Comment: @RichardAtHome  I have edited the original post with the pr();

Answer (score 1):

Before the if try

```
debug(var_dump($posts['Post']['title']));
```

See if it is really set. And I would not use an element for such a trivial line anyways.

Comment: debug(var_dump($posts['Post']['title'])); returns an Undefined index: Post.  However, debug(var_dump($posts[0]['Post']['title'])); returns a string.  Still not working as desired - so if not to use an element, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code given below:

```
echo "<pre>11111";print_r($posts);echo "</pre>";

if(!empty($posts['Post']['title'])) {
                    echo $this->element('postslist');
            } else {
                    echo $this->element('noposts');
            }
```

After you refresh the page, please post the output.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you forgot the foreach loop (assuming $posts contains several posts)

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if(!empty($post['Post']['title'])) {...}
}
```

it is always wise to first debug your variable/array before giving up and posting here at stackoverflow etc. in 99% of all cases this fixes the issue in seconds.

Comment: fortunately I hadn't forgotten the foreach loop - but thanks anyway! Once I am a bit more used to PhP/cake then I shall not be asking so many questions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can print the array using

debug($posts);

and check whether $posts['Post']['title'] contains value or not and then try

if(!empty($posts['Post']['title'])) {
      echo $this->element('postslist');
} else {
      echo $this->element('noposts');
}

or you can use isset() function instead of empty() to do the same
```